# How to add results from pytesseract alto_xml to the original image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am using pytesseract to create searchable pdfs. Since it is important to keep the original look of the images, I want to create the PDF using the original image. However, to improve the OCR result I need to apply some preprocess to the images (deskew, binarization, etc..).

here is how I get a pdf using the processed image.

`pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(adaptive_threshold, lang="frk+deu", config=config)`

So, how could I apply an alto_xml output, for exemple:

`alto= pytesseract.image_to_alto_xml(adaptive_threshold, lang="frk+deu", config=config)`

to the original image and convert it to pdf? Like:

original_image + alto -> convert to a searchable pdf.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There could not be a way to this directly in pyhton because pytesseract is just a python wrapper for the command line version of Tesseract OCR